# view/kill a Windows O/S processes from Ubuntu Server

Tags: ubuntu, process, remote, kill, windows

Is there a Ubuntu version of Sysinternals Process Utilities, which allows Window users to view/control remote processes? I already know I can setup cygwin on Windows and use ssh to remote in. All I'm wondering is if there is a program that view/kill a Windows O/S processes from Ubuntu Server?

Answer (score 0):

There is not a Linux version of anything from Sysinternals. FYI, Process Explorer itself won't work on remote systems.

There might be a WMI client for linux that would accomplish this. There's [this one](http://www.krenger.ch/blog/wmi-commands-from-linux/) that might work for you.